# Not able to open tensorflow lite file in Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agSRN.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XykI8.png)I created a tensorflow lite file and tried to import into Android Studio. I am getting an error that it is not a valid tensorflow lite file

Comment: Have you visualized the file with netron.app? Do you see all details there? Upload a screenshot here.

Comment: I added the screenshot. Thank you so much!

Comment: So basically if you click at the first node, you will see all the details for inputs and outputs. Here U see that input is a tensor of 1...Is it true ir it is a mistake?

Comment: What is the error message that you got (regarding the "not a valid tensorflow lite file" part)?

Comment: It is a text generation network with one character at a time. I pasted the code also

Comment: Do you mind to share the model through tflite-support-team@google.com? We can help you take a look at this from there. Thanks.